# How to maintain logs for front end in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logging

I maintain logs for my backend node js using log4js and it works fine. But I want to do the same for my front end, But I couldn't find a proper package to do that and also in some blogs I came to know that we cannot maintain files in client-side.

So How do I maintain logs for the react js front end?

Note: I want to maintain logs for both info and error, just like this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/log4js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. However, assuming you want to centralize all of your applications logs in one place, then you must call an endpoint that your application exposes and pass the related log data to that endpoint.

1. Create an endpoint that your app can HTTP POST log data to. This endpoint will then invoke your log4js logger
2. Have the client request that endpoint whenever it needs to log data, and send the associated data in the request

Comment: So, in that case, I would have to store the front end logs and backend logs at one place in my backend with separate folders that's fine, but what if the front end is failing to connect my backend itself in that case, I can't log anything, so is there a way to store logs in the front end?

Comment: Well, as long as the client _eventually_ connects to the backend, you can get those logs. You can try sending a request every 5 seconds until the request was successful, for example

Comment: Currently, we are in production and sometimes we face issues like front end doesn't connect to the backend and we want to view the logs usually we can see that by console.log() but my project manager asks to create a log view such issues instead of console.log(), so that's the purpose I want to implement logs

Comment: Without sending that data to your backend, the logs would only live on the clients' device.

Answer (score 0):

One way to log the front end with third party packages is to use `sentry io`. Either the cloud or self hosted versions act as a centralized place for log management. Since it is started as a separate service, even if your backend goes down, it is still possible to trace your frontend logs.